# Why is PowerShell triggering parameter validation again?

Tags: .net, validation, powershell

I have a simple function that takes in string email addresses and validates them using [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress].  If I try to add data that doesn't conform to ValidateScript to the $EmailAddress variable in the function body it will throw an error like ValidateScript is being triggered again.

```
    function Set-EmailAddresses
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=1)]
        [ValidateScript({
            foreach ($address in $_) {
                if ([bool]($address -as [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress])) {
                    return $true
                }
                else {
                    throw "Invalid email address(es)."
                }
            }
        })]
        [string[]]
        $EmailAddresses
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
        $EmailAddresses += "NotASMTPAddress"
        return $true
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

Execute function, provide valid email address.

```
Set-EmailAddresses -EmailAddresses test@test.net
```

Error is thrown when I try to add data that doesn't conform to ValidateScript.

```
Invalid email address(es).
At line:15 char:21
+                     throw "Invalid email address(es)."
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Invalid email address(es).:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Invalid email address(es).
```

If I change the body to pass ValidateScript it works.

```
function Set-EmailAddresses
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=1)]
        [ValidateScript({
            foreach ($address in $_) {
                if ([bool]($address -as [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress])) {
                    return $true
                }
                else {
                    throw "Invalid email address(es)."
                }
            }
        })]
        [string[]]
        $EmailAddresses
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
        $EmailAddresses += "anothersmtp@test.net"
        return $true
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

Comes back fine.

```
Set-EmailAddresses -EmailAddresses test@test.net
True
```

This works fine as well.

```
function Set-EmailAddresses
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=1)]
        [ValidateScript({
            foreach ($address in $_) {
                if ([bool]($address -as [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress])) {
                    return $true
                }
                else {
                    throw "Invalid email address(es)."
                }
            }
        })]
        [string[]]
        $EmailAddresses
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
        $alias = $EmailAddresses
        $alias += "NotASmtpAddress"
        return $true
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

No error thrown.

```
Set-EmailAddresses -EmailAddresses test@test.net
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this happens because your ValidateScript will return `true` if it finds a valid email address at the beginning of the array. In the last script block you posted you had

```
...
Process
    {
        $alias = $EmailAddresses
        $alias += "NotASmtpAddress"
        return $true
    }
...
```

Since you added a valid email address to the start of the array, the Validate script passes. To fix this you could remove the `return $true` in ValidateScript and use a bool variable to track whether there are any invalid email addresses. Then after the foreach loop use an if statement to either `return $true` or throw an exception.

Comment: Yep that was it, I changed the validation to the following and now I can add invalid SMTP addresses in the script body.

[ValidateScript({
            foreach ($address in $_) {
                if (![bool]($address -as [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress])) {
                    throw "$($_) is an invalid email address."
                }
            }
            return $true
        })]